# Could not handle button click in jar file

Tags: java, jar, event-handling

I created a java program using Swing that handles button clicks. I created a jar file of that program. If I run the program from the command line, I can handle button clicks. But when I run from the jar file, I can't do so.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SwingEx {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JButton b = new JButton("click");
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500, 600);
        f.setTitle("Title");
        f.setLayout(null);
        b.setBounds(130, 100, 100, 40);
        f.add(b);
        tf.setBounds(60, 50, 170, 20);
        f.add(tf);
        tf.setVisible(true);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tf.setText("Welcome to Javatpoint.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"?

Comment: I solved that problem. I was creating jar file by using command prompt command as
jar -cvmf myfile.mf myjar.jar Swing.class
And jar file could not load ActionLIstner class and when I use command as
jar -cvmf myfile.mf myjar.jar  *
now jar could load all class